# Ошибка при создании сервера через сокет

Tags: python, сокет

Есть код.

```
import socket
import os

def main():
    HOST = '192.168.0.17'
    PORT = 9090

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    server.bind((HOST, 
                 PORT))

    server.listen()

    client_socket, client_addr = socket.accept()

    print(f"Connected to {client_addr} from {client_socket}")

    cmd_mode = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

После запуска через терминал в линуксе python выдает ошибку.

```
chort@chort-81d2:~/Документы/connect_to_paspb$ python3 server.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "server.py", line 10, in main
    server.bind((HOST,
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Не совсем понимаю в чем ошибка, наеюсь на подсказку. Спасибо

Comment: Вероятно, ошибка в том, что IP-адрес 192.168.0.17 не принадлежит этому компьютеру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сервера вместо

```
HOST = '192.168.0.17'
```

стоит писать

```
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
```